# Set property of control using reflection

Tags: c#, winforms, reflection, properties

How to get/set property of `Control` (in this case `Button`)?

I tried on this way:

```
Type t = Type.GetType("System.Windows.Forms.Button");

PropertyInfo prop = t.GetType().GetProperty("Enabled");

if (null != prop && prop.CanWrite && prop.Name.Equals("button1"))
{
    prop.SetValue(t, "False", null);
}
```

but t is null. What is wrong here?

Comment: `t.GetProperty()` instead of  `t.GetType().GetProperty()`

Comment: `prop.Name` will be `Enabled`, not `button1`

Comment: but t object is null all the time.

Comment: type name should be *assembly qualified*, somethomh like `"System.Windows.Forms.Button, System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"`; note that version and public key can vary  
      `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need the *instance* to set property at, it's `button1`:

```
 object instance = button1;
```

you may want to find it, e.g. let's scan all open forms of `MyForm` type, and look for `Button` with `"button1"` `Name`:

```
 using System.Linq;

 ...

 object instance = Application
   .OpenForms
   .OfType<MyForm>()
   .SelectMany(form => form.Controls.Find("button1", true))
   .OfType<Button>()
   .FirstOrDefault();

 ...
```

Then we are ready for *Reflection*:

```
 var prop = instance.GetType().GetProperty("Enabled");

 if (prop != null && prop.CanWrite && prop.PropertyType == typeof(bool))
   // we set false (bool, not string "False") value
   // for instance button1   
   prop.SetValue(instance, false, null);
```

**Edit:** If you want to obtain `Type` from `string` via `Type.GetType(...)` you want *assembly qualified name*:

```
 string name = typeof(Button).AssemblyQualifiedName;
```

And you'll get something like

```
System.Windows.Forms.Button, System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
```

Demo:

```
Type t = Type.GetType(
  @"System.Windows.Forms.Button, System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089");

MessageBox.Show(t.Name);
```

Comment: This is exact what I was looking for. Thnx.

Comment: If i have something like this
`string mybuttonname = "button1";
Type t = Type.GetType( @"System.Windows.Forms.Button, System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089");
            PropertyInfo prop = t.GetProperty("Enabled");
            if (null != prop && prop.CanWrite && prop.Name.Equals("Enabled"))  
            {
                prop.SetValue((object)mybuttonname, "False", null);
            }
`
I get erorr System.Reflection.TargetException: 'Object does not match target type.'
How to point to specific button in this case?

Comment: You have to **find** the instance, i.e. to obtain `button1` from its name (`"button1"`); you can put `object instance = myForm.Controls.Find("button1", true);`. Please, note, `"False"` is of type `string`, and that's why not correct; it should be `false` of type `bool`

Comment: Is there any other way to avoid finding control if I know control name and type? The problem is for example if I have toolbar button control then i can't find control easily on form. I'm looking somehow to point to control using control name... I don't know is this even possible in C#.

Comment: Well, `ToolBarButton` is not of type `Control`, but just a `Component`; that's why we have to search in a *different way*; you can enumerate all `ToolBar` and analyze their `Buttons` collections